# jQuery - Fill div with content from the title attribute when link is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, click, title

I'm working on a small page that allows people to create a list of various YouTube videos (with custom title and description) and have them show the video in an iFrame on the same page. All of this is already implemented and working fine.

But on top of that, I would also like to have the title of the video shown in a div (#tv-title), but this part is something I can't seem to figure out.

Ideally I would want the content that's provided in the -tag's title attribute to be displayed in a div.

Anyone that can help me with this?

This is how my code looks at the moment:

```
<div id="tv-title">This is where the title-attribute content should go</div>
<iframe name="tv-frame" id="tv-frame" src="#" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<ul id="tv-list">
<li>
<a href="#" target="tv-frame" title="Title 1"><span class="li-title">Title 1</span><span class="li-description">Description 1</span></a>
<a href="#" target="tv-frame" title="Title 2"><span class="li-title">Title 2</span><span class="li-description">Description 2</span></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
$('a[target="tv-frame"]').on('click',function(e){
    $('#tv-title').text(this.title);
});
```

Comment: That works great, thanks!

Additional question: I would like to have the div filled with the title attribute of the first link in the list when the page is done loading. How would you go about doing that?

I've already figured something similar out by assigning a class to the first item in the list when the page loads, but I can't think of a way to combine that script with your script to get the best result.

Comment: @Bolteh You can do this on page load `--->` `$('#tv-title').text($('a[target="tv-frame"]')[0].title);`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$("a").on('click',function(){
    var title=$(this).attr("title");
    $("#tv-title").text(title);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/6DDu6/

```
$('a[target="tv-frame"]').click(function(){
    $('#tv-title').text($(this).attr('title'));
});
```